# TinyMCE does not add html tags into database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, tinymce-4

I have an issue with TinyMCE.

I put in

```
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({selector: 'textarea'});</script>
```

It loads the textarea fine, but no HTML tags goes into my database. It automatically worked on another site i was working on but it currently doesn't work on this one..

What could be the reason of this?

Code below is directly from what the form is going to load when submitting and further down you'll see my HTML code

```
    <?php 

include '../dbh.php';

$sDay = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'sDay', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$sMonth = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'sMonth', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$sYear = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'sYear', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$eDay = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'eDay', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$eMonth = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'eMonth', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$eYear = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'eYear', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$eCreated = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'eCreated', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$eTitle = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'eTitle', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$eAuthor = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'eAuthor', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$eDescription = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'eDescription', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$sql = "INSERT INTO events (id, eTitle, eAuthor, eStartDate, sDay, sMonth, sYear, eEndDate, eDay, eMonth, eYear, eDescription, eCreated, IsDeleted, eActive)
            VALUES (NULL, '$eTitle', '$eAuthor', '$sYear-$sMonth-$sDay', '$sDay', '$sMonth', '$sYear', '$eYear-$eMonth-$eDay',$eDay, $eMonth, $eYear, '$eDescription', '$eCreated', '0', '0');";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

header("Location: ../events.php");
```

```html
<div class="input-field col col-lg-12">
  <label for="eDescription">Beskrivelse</label>
  <textarea name="eDescription" id="eDescription" type="text"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: What value are you getting after submitting the form? Are you processing anything on the value before storing? Show the whole code of storing data in database.

Comment: FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING filter removes HTML tags.

Comment: I've edited the post with the code.

I tried to look for anything doing something to the value before it stores it but couldn't find any. I tried output the Description but no tags at all

Comment: @Maadinsh Oh wow.. I did not know that! what can I do instead?

Comment: Just escape the input with mysqli_real_escape_string.
Have a look at http://htmlpurifier.org/ to add some protection against malicious code, there is no simple built in way to safely clean and validate user provided html if you want to allow any tags and formatting.

Comment: I see, thank you! :)